# What do i type in to add “SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc–7.3.0-mingw-64-bit” to my path?

Tags: c++

I have been doing research for months and I can not find a straight answer. I've tried the Atom Discussion, cplusplus.com, and countless hours of searching the web. Please help!!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the editor that you use, but with the compiler and how you build your programs. Please show what you tried before and what exactly doesn't work. SFML has guides [here](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/).

Comment: Is there any graphics header (beside <graphics.h>) that you can use for Atom?

Comment: Again, none of this is related to the text editor that you use. What libraries you can use depends on the platform and the compiler. There is probably nothing stopping you from using SFML. Just look at the link I provided above.

Comment: I have. The problem I'm having is i don't know how to connect the SFML to Atom or SFML to my path. I have the SFML downloaded and atom but i don't now how to add it to my path.

Comment: I have said multiple times that it has nothing to do with your text editor (Atom). It has to do with the compiler and how you compile your program. What compiler are you using and how are you compiling your programs?

Comment: Just how do I add SFML to my path so it works on atom. SFML has certain downloads for different programs and there is no for atom but there is a 64-bit download that can be connected to atom. The program is vital becauce thre is certain paths that need the be connected to certin things.

Comment: Sorry, but I can not make my last comments any clearer. If you can't provide answers to the questions I asked you, there is no way I can help you.

Comment: My question is: What is the correct download for SFML and how do I add it to my path?

Comment: Have you looked at the tutorial? https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-linux.php

Comment: Im using windows. I've looked at all of the tutorials, none help.